# How to install an Eclipse project?

Tags: installation, eclipse

I've downloaded the latest version of Eclipse because I got interested in one of its projects.

Now from the [Getting started section](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/latest/xtext.html#getting-started) I've got this link to download the project: http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/downloads/

I have unzipped the file and got the following:

```
ls -F tmf-xtext-Update-1.0.0/

artifacts.jar   content.jar features/   plugins/    site.xml
```

Where am I supposed to copy these files to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't supposed to copy the files. Use Help > Install New Software and give it the URL.

Except the repository name is actually  http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/updates/releases/ as shown in http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/updates/

Comment: I wish they have provided that link instead. Thank you. BTW I figured out by this answer, that I can install that folder by adding it as a `Local` source.